# HTTP live stream AVAsset

Tags: opencv

I am implementing a n HTTP live streaming player with OSX using avplayer. 
I am able to stream it properly seek and get duration timing etc.
Now i want to take screen shots and process the frames from it using OpenCV.
I went for using AVASSetImageGenerator. But there is no audio and video tracks with the AVAsset which is associated with player.currentItem.

The tracks are appearing in player.currentItem.tracks.
So i am not able to sue AVAssetGenerator. Can anybody help to find out a solution to extract screenshots and individual frames in such a scenario?

Please find the code below how i am initiating an HTTP live stream

Thanks in advance.

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
playeritem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

[playeritem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:AVSPPlayerStatusContext];
[self setPlayer:[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playeritem]];
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"player.rate" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:AVSPPlayerRateContext];
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"player.currentItem.status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:AVSPPlayerItemStatusContext];
AVPlayerLayer *newPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:[self player]];
[newPlayerLayer setFrame:[[[self playerView] layer] bounds]];
[newPlayerLayer setAutoresizingMask:kCALayerWidthSizable | kCALayerHeightSizable];
[newPlayerLayer setHidden:YES];
[[[self playerView] layer] addSublayer:newPlayerLayer];
[self setPlayerLayer:newPlayerLayer];
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playerLayer.readyForDisplay" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:AVSPPlayerLayerReadyForDisplay];
[self.player play];
```

Following is how i am checking whether video track is present with the Asset

```
case AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay:

                [self setTimeObserverToken:[[self player] addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(1, 10) queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
                    [[self timeSlider] setDoubleValue:CMTimeGetSeconds(time)];
                    NSLog(@"%f,%f,%f",[self currentTime],[self duration],[[self player] rate]);
                    AVPlayerItem *item = playeritem;
                    if(item.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)
                    {
                    AVAsset *asset = (AVAsset *)item.asset;
                    long audiotracks = [[asset tracks] count];
                    long videotracks = [[asset availableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions]count];

                    NSLog(@"Track info Audio = %ld,Video=%ld",audiotracks,videotracks);
                    }
                }]];



                AVPlayerItem *item = self.player.currentItem;
                if(item.status != AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)
                    return;
                AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset *)item.asset;
                long audiotracks = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]count];
                long videotracks = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]count];

                NSLog(@"Track info Audio = %ld,Video=%ld",audiotracks,videotracks);
```

Comment: Hi , How you managed to get  tracks using HLS? please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an older question but in case someone needs help for that i have an answer

```
AVURLAsset *asset = /* Your Asset here! */;
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter =  kCMTimeZero;
generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore =  kCMTimeZero;
for (Float64 i = 0; i < CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration) *  /* Put the FPS of the source video here */ ; i++){
    @autoreleasepool {
        CMTime time = CMTimeMake(i, /* Put the FPS of the source video here */);

        NSError *err;
        CMTime actualTime;
        CGImageRef image = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:&actualTime error:&err];

        // Do what you want with the image, for example save it as UIImage
        UIImage *generatedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image];

        CGImageRelease(image);
    }
}
```

You can easily get the FPS of a Video by using this code:

```
float fps=0.00;
if (asset) {
    AVAssetTrack * videoATrack = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo][0];
    if(videoATrack)
    {
        fps = [videoATrack nominalFrameRate];
    }
}
```

Hope that helps someone who is asking how to get all frames from a video or just some specific (with CMTime for example) frames. Please bear in mind, that saving all frames to an array can impact the memory hardly!

Comment: Love it. I came here in 2016 and needed this answer. Thanks!